# Detect change to traffic layer in HERE Maps API

Tags: javascript, here-api

When a user turns the traffic layer on or off in the HERE Maps Javascript API 3.1, I want to capture this event.  However, I haven't found a way to detect this.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible:

```
// assuming defaultLayers object instantiated before

map.getLayers().addEventListener('add', (e) => {
  (e.added === defaultLayers.vector.normal.traffic) && console.log('Vector traffic layer added');
})
```

if you call setBaseLayer instead of addLayer then you can add baselayerchange event listener on map